# Problem in pinch in and pinch out of 3D Animation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 3d, maya

I'm new here. I'm working on a project based on Augmented Reality and I'm playing 3D animations in that application. I want to add a feature to the application of pinch in and pinch out of any 3D Animation. I am facing a problem in Pinch in and Pinch out of a 3D Animation. I have tried the code provided in the unity form but there was a problem with orthogonal camera.

**Unity Site Code**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PinchZoom : MonoBehaviour

{
public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the field of view in perspective mode.
public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the orthographic size in orthographic mode.


void Update()
{
    // If there are two touches on the device...
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // If the camera is orthographic...
        if (camera.isOrthoGraphic)
        {
            // ... change the orthographic size based on the change in distance between the touches.
            camera.orthographicSize += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

            // Make sure the orthographic size never drops below zero.
            camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(camera.orthographicSize, 0.1f);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
            camera.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;

            // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
            camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(camera.fieldOfView, 0.1f, 179.9f);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**My try**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pinch_MUN : MonoBehaviour {

public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the field of view in perspective mode.
public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the orthographic size in orthographic mode.


void Update()
{
    // If there are two touches on the device...
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // If the camera is orthographic...
        if (GetComponent<Camera>().orthographic == true)
        {
            // ... change the orthographic size based on the change in distance between the touches.
            GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

            // Make sure the orthographic size never drops below zero.
            GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize, 0.1f);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
            GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;

            // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
            GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, 0.1f, 179.9f);
        }
    }
}
```

}

It doesn't matters for me, that either we pinch the camera or simply pinch the 3D animation in the view.
Please help me to figure out my mistake, according to the above scenario.
Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own gesture detection logic, use a ready-made solution (I've used [TouchKit](https://github.com/prime31/TouchKit) in a few of my projects). In AR, you can't modify the camera properties (position *or* fov) as it would put your virtual camera out of sync with the physical camera. You should progressively scale the game object up and down to adjust size.

Comment: Thanks, but this help me to zoom in and out the game objects?

Comment: Uh... Yes it does?

Comment: it's lil bit difficult to implement.

Comment: Yes, though not that much, and that's why you get grades or money to do it. Asking questions on SO in OK, asking people to do your work for you is not.